# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function with continious derivatives $f',f^{(2)},f^{(3)},f^{(4)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function with continious derivatives $f',f^{(2)},f^{(3)},f^{(4)}$.

Take $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f'(a)=f^{(2)}(a)=f^{(3)}(a)=0$.

Now I want to prove that $f$ has a local minimum in $a$ if $f^{(4)}(a)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor or mean-value theorem, e.g.,
$$
f(x) = f(a) + \frac1{4!} f^{(4)}(\xi)\cdot (x-a)^4
$$
where $\xi$ is between $x$ and $a$. By continuity, there is a neighborhood of $a$ such that $f^{(4)}(\xi) \ge \frac12f^{(4)}(a)>0$ for all $\xi$ in this neighorhood.
Now choose $x$ in that neighborhood to conclude $f(x)>f(a)$.